# SQL to get counts of related entities in separate tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a schema that resembles the following in a Postgresql database:

[image: schema]

So I have a `players` table and two join tables to `matches`.

The first join table, `matches_players`, defines the players who played in a given match.
The second, `scorers`, defines which players scored a goal in a given match. It's possible to have multiple rows for the same player and match in the `scorers` table. Each row indicates a single goal scored, so if a player scored 3 goals in a match there would be 3 rows with that `match_id` and `player_id`.

I'm trying to write a query that will return me a table of player IDs along with counts of matches played and goals scored for each player. E.g.

| player_id | matches_played | goals_scored |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | 2 |
| 2 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 2 | 0 |

As an extension to this, **I'd like to be able to filter the results by conditions on the `match`**. E.g. get the above results only for matches played after a certain date.

This query seems to do the job for the simple case, but I'm unsure of how to filter by match conditions as there are 2 join paths to `matches`.

```
SELECT p.id player_id,
       COUNT(DISTINCT m.match_id) matches_played,
       COUNT(DISTINCT s.id) goals_scored
FROM players p
LEFT JOIN matches_players mp ON mp.player_id = p.id
LEFT JOIN scorers s ON s.player_id = p.id
GROUP BY p.id
```

(It might be worth noting that there's no restriction between rows appearing in `scorers` and `matches_players`. Theorectically a player could have 1 or more rows for a given match for `scorers` but no row for that match in `matches_players`. In this case they'd have a `matches_played` = 0 and `goals_scored` = 1.

This is because team selection is a different flow to recording match stats. This is something that might be fixed in the future but is tolerable for now).

Comment: Not having a row in `matches_players` for a player that participated in a match is a flaw in your app logic.

Comment: indeed it might be, but that isn't really the concern of this question. It is something that I'm looking at addressing in the future

Comment: How can someone score a goal in a match he did not play?

Comment: He cannot, but this is not the subject of this question. I accept that it's possible that the database may not reflect reality. The solution is probably to have the `scorers` table have a foreign key to `matches_players` rather than `players`, but at the time this was the approach taken

Comment: Are you Ok with results containing 0 matches, 1 goal? (ii) if a player did not play a match and didn't score should the result still contain a row for that player?

Comment: yeah, if a player played 0 matches they should not appear in the results, even if a goal exists for them

Answer (score 4):

The problem for your requirement is to get the matches that a player has played.
For this, you need to take account the `match_id`s from both `matches_players` and `scorers` and you can get them in a subquery with `UNION`.
Then you need `LEFT` joins of `players` to the subquery and `scorers` and aggregation:

```
SELECT p.id player_id,
       COUNT(DISTINCT m.match_id) matches_played,
       COUNT(DISTINCT s.id) goals_scored
FROM players p
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT player_id, match_id FROM matches_players
  UNION
  SELECT player_id, match_id FROM scorers
) m ON m.player_id = p.id
LEFT JOIN scorers s ON s.player_id = p.id
GROUP BY p.id
```

Comment: Sorry, maybe I wasn't 100% clear. The `scorers` table doesn't influence the `matches_played` result; only the `matches_players` table. In which case I guess it makes the query quite simple; I think I was missing the `DISTINCT`

Comment: @harryg then what is the problem? Just join and aggregate. Of course you will not get correct results for `matches_played` since there may be matches missing for some players.

Comment: I think that's fine. I think I was just being a bit slow last night. As I mention, it is possible for a player to have a non-zero "goals scored" whilst having 0 "matches played" due to the issue with the schema. That's OK for now though. Thanks for your help

Comment: On second thoughts, the main issue I was having was filtering by match conditions. As the 2 tables are both joined to matches I'm having trouble writing the joins with the required conditions. I've updated my question to include this

Comment: @harryg your question was unclear as it was. Now you changed the requirement and made it more unclear because there is no date column in any of the 3 tables and also invalidated any answers that you received.

Answer (score 0):

So far, the following seems to do the trick:

```
select t1.player_id
    , sum(case coalesce(t2.match_id,-1) when -1 then 0 else 1 end) as matches_played
    , sum(case coalesce(t3.match_id,-1) when -1 then 0 else 1 end) as goals_scored
from players as t1
left join matches_players as t2 on (t1.player_id=t2.player_id)
left join scorers as t3 on (t2.match_id=t3.match_id and t1.player_id=t3.player_id)
group by t1.player_id
order by t1.player_id
;
```

And [here is the fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rLAVTmqAuxhtAjsyGPwLMA/0)!

**Edit 1** I just saw the comments and hadn't anticipated "design flaw". In this case, you need forpas's solution because the union is the only way to get all the matches (the ones in matches and the ones in scores). Also, one of the left joins would break in my case due to the match not being in matches, easily fixable but there is no point given the other solution is what you need :)